# How to join parts of two strings together in python

Tags: python, string

I have the following two `strings`:

```
request= "1/1/1.3.45.3.6/3/4
reply= "1/2/3"
```

I want to return a new `string`, which concatenates the `1.3.45.3.6` of `request` with `2` of `reply` to return a `list` which contains the `string`.

Output should be a `list`:

```
result= ["1.3.45.3.6.2"]
```

I have the following method, that doesn't work. 
The inputs to the method are both strings.

```
def concatentatestring(request, response):
    oidStatusValueList = [f"{i.split('/')[2]}.{j.split('/')[2]}" \
       for i in request for j in response \
           if (i.split('/')[1] == j.split('/')[1]) ]
```

Comment: Updated the code in the question. It was a typo.

Comment: No problem, but since you're always guaranteed a single element list (if I'm reading this correctly), why bother making it a list? `print(f"{request.split('/')[2]}.{response.split('/')[1]}")` gives your desired output, no need to iterate.

Comment: How do you decide which parts of the strings should be merged?

Comment: I want to use a list

Comment: @LauraSmith see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont use a list comprehension as you are not iterating over request and response

```
>> request= "1/1/1.3.45.3.6/3/4"
>>> reply= "1/2/3"
>>> [f"{request.split('/')[2]}.{reply.split('/')[1]}"]
['1.3.45.3.6.2']
```

So your `concatentatestring` function would look like

```
>>> def concatentatestring(request, response):
...     return [f"{request.split('/')[2]}.{response.split('/')[1]}"]
... 
>>> 
>>> concatentatestring(request, reply)
['1.3.45.3.6.2']
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding two strings can be done with the `+` operator or using an f-string (I don't believe theres much if any performance difference)

You can split a string with the `split` method as you used and then if the format of the request and the response will always be the same you know to get the 2 element of the split request and the 1 element of the split response

```
def addstring(request, response):
    return [request.split('/')[2] + '.' + response.split('/')[1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

you are iterating through every letter in the strings in the for loops you wrote.

I believe this can do what you are asking for:

```
request= "1/1/1.3.45.3.6/3/4"
reply= "1/2/3"

def concatentatestring(request, response):
    request_splited=request.split('/') # =["1","1","1.3.45.3.6","3","4"]
    response_splited=response.split('/') # =["1","2","3"]
    if request_splited[1] == response_splited[1]:
        return [f'{request_splited[2]}.{response_splited[1]}']
    else:
        ...
```

Comment: For example, I also need to check if the second index of the request and reply string are equal before concatenating them together. How would I do that?

Comment: and if they are not equal? I edited the response to check that but without a case for if they are not equal

Answer (score 0):

Your code was not quite doing it as you needed to properly iterate through the strings. You also should split them before the list comprehension. To use both the index and the value at that index, you can use `enumerate` and, lastly, you should check to make sure you have not reached the end of the strings or it could cause errors.

This is what you are looking for:

```
request = "1/1/1.3.45.3.6/3/4"
reply = "1/2/3"

def concatenateStrings(request, response):
    reqs = request.split("/")
    resps = response.split("/")
    oidStatusValueList = [f"{reqs[i+1]}.{resps[j+1]}" \
       for i, req in enumerate(reqs) for j, resp in enumerate(resps) \
           if (req == resp and i<len(reqs)-1 and j<len(resps)-1) ]
    return oidStatusValueList

result = concatenateStrings(request, reply)
print(result)
```

Your expected output is also incorrect considering what you are inputting and your criteria for joining the strings. This code results in:

```
['1.2', '1.3.45.3.6.2']
```